# Is there a makefile for OpenEdge ABL?

Tags: makefile, progress-4gl, openedge

I'm desperately looking for a way to make a makefile for Progress OpenEdge ABL, and let it compile only a subset of the application, based on what source file has changed.

Has anyone set up anything like this? I've used makefiles before in C applications, but never under Windows with an environment where not all files follow a set naming convention (e.g. abc/xxx may be a program, or an include).

Comment: Is your codebase that big that you can't compile the whole thing regardless?

Comment: It takes about an hour on character, and 2 hours on GUI. I blame virtual machines...
I'm looking for a simple way to automate compiles where 1 include changes, without having to manually trace through code to see where that include is used.

Comment: Are you using Roundtable for version control? If so, I believe they have deployment options. What we did is write a program that creates a install script from the roundtable records, since Roundtable keeps track of dependencies.

Comment: No, we're using Subversion, and looking into Git. The dependencies that are stored in Roundtable, are they based on the XREF information of the compilation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PCT](https://code.google.com/p/pct/wiki/InstallDocumentation) could be the answer, is a JAR that you can use in an ANT script and manages Progress compilations with many several options, including multithreading or just recompiling what is required.

Comment: I didn't realize Ant/PCT could be used for partial compiles, I thought it was more a deployment of the whole system. But now I see the options in PCTCompile include a forceCompile, which leads me to believe it looks at dependencies. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, when I have tried, it only recompiles whatever needs to be recompiled, but better to double check it for complicated dependencies.